# Can't run protractor on internet explorer

Tags: protractor

I try to run protractor on IE11 and i keep get this failuer:

> E/launcher - Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.

I did set in explorer for all zones but still  get this error.

my conf.js file is:

```
exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'internet explorer'
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the configuration file location passed
  // to protractor (in this example conf.js).
  // They may include glob patterns.
  specs: ['todo-spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
  }
};
```

Help please.
Shaked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security Tab and set all zones to the same protected mode (can be enabled or disabled).

Answer (score 0):

Try including these capabilities:

```
capabilities: {
    ...
    "ignoreProtectedModeSettings": true
}
```

Comment: didn't work. I got new error:
[17:39:56] E/configParser - Error code: 105
[17:39:56] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file conf.js
[17:39:56] E/configParser - C:\Users\moran\Protractor\conf.js:9
        'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: This is because your config.js is not properly formatted. Something is missing. The capabilities does not throw an error.